# how to Copy listView selected items into an array

Tags: c#, forms, listview

I'm trying to get listView items into an array..
in listBox

```
    listBox1.SelectedItems
```

would do the trick.
But it didn't work in listView...
any Ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this,

```
var myList = new List<string>();
foreach(ListViewItem Item in ListView.SelectedItems)
{
   myList.add(Item.Text.ToString());
}
var myArray = myList.ToArray();
```

Comment: What if you want to do the same thing and are using a ListBox now a ListView?